# Random characteres at end of string

Tags: c, string, gcc

I made a function to encrypt a string in C (with GCC) but I'm getting random characters at end of the decrypted string.
The function will save the length of input string at first character and the key used (first character -1) at second. All strings to be encrypted have a length between 10 and 30 so I hope there is no problem when converting to storing as char.

Whole code here:

```
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //malloc
#include <string.h> //strlen

char* x(const char* toEncrypt);
char* y(const char* toDecrypt);

int main() {
    const char *secret = "hellohello";
    printf("original: %s\n", secret);

    const char* crypted = x(secret);
    printf("crypted: %s\n", crypted);

    const char* decrypted = y(crypted);
    printf("decrypted: %s\n", decrypted);

    return 0;
}

char* x(const char* toEncrypt) {
    printf("x->toEncrypt = %s\n", toEncrypt);

    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    int length = strlen(toEncrypt);
    printf("\tx->length = %d\n", length);

    char key = ((char)(*toEncrypt))-1;
    printf("\tx->key = %c\n", key);

    char* output = (char*)malloc(length+3); //toEncrypt length + (length + key + null)

    output[offset++] = (char)length;
    output[offset++] = key;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\toffset = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, offset, toEncrypt[i]);
        output[offset++] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key;
    }
    output[offset] = '\0';

    printf("\tx->output = %s\n", output);
    return output;
}

char* y(const char* toDecrypt) {
    printf("y->toDecrypt = %s\n", toDecrypt);

    int offset = 0, i = 0;
    int length = (int)toDecrypt[offset++] ;
    printf("\tx->length = %d\n", length);

    char key = (char)toDecrypt[offset++];
    printf("\ty->key = %c\n", key);

    char* output = (char*)malloc(length+1);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\toffset = %d\tchar = %c\n", i, offset, (char)toDecrypt[offset] ^key);
        output[i] = toDecrypt[offset++] ^ key;
    }

    output[offset] = '\0';

    printf("\ty->output = %s\n", output);
    return output;
}
```

And the output:

```
original: hellohello
x->toEncrypt = hellohello
        x->length = 10
        x->key = g
i = 0   offset = 2      char = h
i = 1   offset = 3      char = e
i = 2   offset = 4      char = l
i = 3   offset = 5      char = l
i = 4   offset = 6      char = o
i = 5   offset = 7      char = h
i = 6   offset = 8      char = e
i = 7   offset = 9      char = l
i = 8   offset = 10     char = l
i = 9   offset = 11     char = o
        x->output =
g
crypted:
g
y->toDecrypt =
g
        x->length = 10
        y->key = g
i = 0   offset = 2      char = h
i = 1   offset = 3      char = e
i = 2   offset = 4      char = l
i = 3   offset = 5      char = l
i = 4   offset = 6      char = o
i = 5   offset = 7      char = h
i = 6   offset = 8      char = e
i = 7   offset = 9      char = l
i = 8   offset = 10     char = l
i = 9   offset = 11     char = o
        y->output = hellohellobe
decrypted: hellohellobe
```

Comment: You should always check the return value from `malloc()`, and don't cast the return value.

Comment: My magic crystal ball tells me you're not writing the null terminator where you think you are. Reading the code confirms this. In `y` did you figure out the difference between `offset` and `i`?

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem lies in this statement (in function `y()` — the same statement in function `x()` is OK):

```
output[offset] = '\0';
```

It should have been:

```
output[i] = '\0';
```

Changing this should work.